# Поиск в массиве дробных чисел

Tags: python, массивы, математика, динамические-массивы

На вход программе подается 1 миллиард больших дробных чисел. После этого компьютер может обрабатывать их любым образом 1 час.
Далее подаются запросы вида: есть ли число k в данном массиве? Необходимо не более, чем за 1/1000 секунды отвечать на этот запрос. Известно, что этого времени хватит на примерно 1 млн сравнений чисел.

Каким образом предлагается реализовать подготовку массива чисел на протяжении первого часа?

Как организовать настолько быстрый ответ на запросы?

Comment: Если бы это был С++, я бы попробовал хеш-таблицу для пары числитель+знаменатель (приведенной к несократимому виду). Как выглядит хеш-таблица в Python, не подскажу... Но есть вопрос — что конкретно значит "больших дробных чисел"?

Comment: Это абстрактная задача с интервью. Так что конкретики по "большим дробным числам" к сожалению нету (

Comment: Отсортировать (для миллиарда чисел сортировка скорее всего займёт не более нескольких секунд, может быть минуты). Бинарный поиск среди миллиарда элементов потребует не более 30 сравнений за запрос.

Comment: На массиве в 10 миллионов время поиска составило 3.71 секунду, так что действительно выгоднее всего использовать словарь в таком случае.

Comment: Если этот вопрос с интервью, если вы на него не смогли ответить ни на самом интервью ни после поискав в Гуугле, если вы пришли на форум искать ответ и даже после абсолютно точной и однозначной подсказки не поняли как найти ответ, то......... Ну какой словарь???? Вам же однозначно сказали - сортировка и бинарный поиск. Думаю, что надо срочно подтягивать базовые основы информатики.

Comment: В память миллиард больших дробных чисел помещается?

Comment: @passant А словать в Python разве не работает именно таким образом?